# accidentally moved everything in user home directory how to undo a script

Tags: bash, scripts

I was trying to move files from one dir to another and I missed up my home director can someone help me undo this script. everything in my home dir now put in dir called myfiles. I am on Ubuntu 20.04

```
mv ~/my_files/master_cs/jv/foundation_cls/ -v !("~/my_files/master_cs/jv/foundation_cls/cop_5007") ~/my_files/master_cs/jv/foundation_cls/code_snipt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am getting your question right then you can simply move back directories to home folder by opening your teriminal and doing this:

```
cd ~/my_files
mv * ../
```

Comment: this did not solve the problem now everything in my_files is in /home/user and still unable 
to access system dir like Document and  all those files/ dirs  in the home/user can not find them ``` customized-script   IdeaProjects      Pictures      snap
 Desktop             MOK.der           playground1   Templates
 Documents           MOK.priv          playground2   Vagrantfile
 Downloads           Music             play_sh       Videos
 eclipse             my_files          Public       'VirtualBox VMs'
 eclipse-workspace   online_projects   shellclass
```

Comment: How I can move back everything from home dir to my_files which is also now in my home dir? I think I know how to fixed if I can return back to the previous state?

Comment: I’m not sure why the suggested answer didn’t work. I wonder if you might find this easiest to do via the gui? Go into the folder you accidentally moved everything, make sure you can see hidden files, select everything with the mouse, right-click and cut-and-paste into the home folder. I think (someone correct me if I’m wrong) it should be near-instantaneous because nothing actually has to move if the things you’re moving are in a sub-folder.

Comment: What is your real problem? Can't you login in your home directory anymore? If you move with a complicated command, are you not able to undo the move your self? Clarify your question: use "edit".

Comment: @Will the suggested answer worked but in that panic mood I forget to do `` mv * `` so I can move everything from the files to the home directory. Now things work just fine. I just check the hidden file still in home. And thanks @vanaium

Comment: Thanks for posting back that you’ve sorted it - lesson for us all that doing anything on the command line in a panic is a bad idea! Well done for fixing it.